# fetch entire details from csv file by typing name in textbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

**I Have four TextBox As Shown Below**

Name,Surname,City,State

I have my studentdetails.csv file in particular path

```
filepath="C:\\Users\\vikas\\Desktop\\studentdetails.csv"
```

.csv file contains below details in it

```
vikas,gadhi,mumbai,maharashtra

prem,yogi,kolkata,maha

roja,goal,orissa,oya

ram,kala,goa,barka
```

Now i have created a class file called Userdetails (see it in the solution explorer)

[solution explorer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOLR4.png)
Now on main form1 backend code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace studentdetails
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\vikas\\Desktop\\fetch.csv";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        UserDetails SearchFor(String searchName)
        {
            var strLines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
            foreach (var line in strLines)
            {
                var bits = line.Split(',');
                if (bits[0].Equals(searchName))
                {
                    return new UserDetails()
                    {           
                        surname = bits[1],
                        city = bits[2],
                        state = bits[3],                     
                    };
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Issue : how do i display details of student surname,city,state when i type name in textbox => textname as ram

Output :
[output][3]
when i type name as ram in textname field the remaining details should be fetched and displayed in the rest textboxes

How do i call the details write code please

Comment: Welcome to SO. I could think two ways for building that you want. a) place a button in the form and register a handler for the click event of the button ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=netframework-4.8). In the event handler you could call the `SearchFor` method and if the value that is returned is not null, you could read the value of `UserDetails` properties and populate the corresponding text box controls `Text` property.

Comment: b) Register an event handler for the `TextChanged` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netframework-4.8) event of the text box with the name and then do exactly the same as in the a) case.